# Wow Slider image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used wow slider in my web page. It is working fine. But I am facing one problem.

The css is

```
#wowslider-container1 { 
    zoom: 1; 
    position: relative; 
    max-width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:100;
    border:none;
    text-align:left; /* reset align=center */
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_images{
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images a{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    color:transparent;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_images img{
    width:100%;
    border:none 0;
    max-width: none;
}
#wowslider-container1 a{ 
    text-decoration: none; 
    outline: none; 
    border: none; 
}
```

HTML is:

```
<div id="wowslider-container1">
      <div class="ws_images">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="images/amazing_sunset.jpg" alt="amazing sunset" title="amazing sunset amazing sunset amazing sunset amazing sunset" /></li>
          <li><img src="images/apple_tree.jpg" alt="apple tree" title="apple tree"/></li>
          <li><img src="images/beutiful_landscape.jpg" alt="beutiful landscape" title="beautiful landscape"/></li>
          <li><img src="images/lightbox-btn-prev.gif" alt="nature" title="nature" width="63" height="32"/></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

  <!-- Generated by WOWSlider.com v2.2 -->
</div>
```

If the client wants to upload a small size the image is not re-sized. But he upload a large size the image is resized. Totally he is not want to set the width and height. Please refer the last li. The image size is 63*62. But it is automatically re-sized to 500px. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Within the WowSlider application (paid version), you have the option to set the height and width of the slider (either preset or custom). It appears that you have selected a width of 960px.

You also have the option to preserver an image's aspect ratio and/or stretch small images. Click on the wrench icon, click on Images, and you'll see the option on the right.

One note -- your client has an incredibly small image if it is only 63px by 62px. If you stretch that up to 960px wide, it is going to be incredibly distorted and pixelated. In this instance, I would request a higher quality image from the client.